# How to connect the App Maker to Google Cloud apis

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-maker

I am new to the App Maker, just curious, can the App Maker connect to Google Cloud apis, such as Google Speech api? and where should I start with? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**G Suite Services**

Some APIs are available out of the box. You can find docs for all of them in Apps Script reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/
[image: G Suite Services]

**Advanced Google Services**

Even more, you can easily plug-in Advanced Google Services:
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/settings#advanced_google_services
[image: Add Advanced Google Services]

**Other Services**

If you need something special... Then you can try to enable that specific API for your Cloud Project and talk to it using oAuth(I'm not 100% sure, never tried it myself). You can access your Cloud Project by viewing you deployment logs: `Settings -> Deployments -> Deployment Logs`
[image: View deployment logs]

This will redirect you to Google Cloud Console. There you'll be enable services you need.
[image: Cloud Platform]

You can find further steps by following the link:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is very helpful. I also did a little bit research, and I think the 3rd one you mentioned would fit my purpose. Since App Maker runs in Google App Script, is that means I should go through the App Script to connect to GCP APIs? Here is a reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

Comment: Absolutely! Apps Script is App Maker's runtime. Thank you for finding this link.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Vision Template](https://appmakeruniversity.com/downloads/image-management-with-google-vision/) at AMU would be a perfect example to start from. You would need to use the Speech URLs, Your API Key and modify the post. This is a working example however to get you going.

Comment: Thanks James, I will definitely check it out!